# Showing empty state when filtered results are 0 in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got this `searchView` which I use to filter recyclerView. So when there is no results for some search query, I want to show `textView` to user by setting its visibility to `VISIBLE`. So in searchView listener, I do:

```
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                if (adapter.getItemCount()<=0){
                    emptyStateConatiner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else  emptyStateConatiner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                return false;
            }
```

But this doesn't work as I would expect, because when I type non existing search query, it first shows empty `recyclerView` and only after that, if I type additional letter to that query, I get `emptyStateContainer` shown.

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior?

Here is adapter code:
package com.app.userprofile;

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.app.R;
import com.app.data.webservice.collection_response.Datum;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BasicUserProfileInfoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasicUserProfileInfoListAdapter.BasicInfoViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Datum> offeredChoices = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Datum> offeredChoicesFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Datum> previouslySelectedChoices = new ArrayList<>();


    private Resources resources;
    private ItemClickCallback clickCallback;

    //for single choices
    int mCheckedPostion=-1;

    public BasicUserProfileInfoListAdapter(ItemClickCallback clickCallback){
        this.clickCallback = clickCallback;
    }

    public void setList(List<Datum> datumList) {
        this.offeredChoices = datumList;
        this.offeredChoicesFiltered = datumList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }






    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BasicInfoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.basic_choice_item, viewGroup, false);
        if (resources == null) {
            resources = itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources();
        }

        return new BasicInfoViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BasicInfoViewHolder basicInfoViewHolder, final int i) {
        final Datum currentData = offeredChoicesFiltered.get(i);

        basicInfoViewHolder.basicInfoCheckBox.setText(currentData.getDesc());
        //TODO if currentData equals some choice in previouslySelectedChoices, than mark it checked and add it to selected choices via interface

       if (clickCallback instanceof MultipleChoiceItemClickCallback && previouslySelectedChoices!=null && !previouslySelectedChoices.isEmpty()){
           boolean shouldCheck=false;
           for (Datum data:previouslySelectedChoices) {
               if ((data.getId().equals(currentData.getId()))/*&& data.getDesc().equals(currentData.getDesc())*/){
                   shouldCheck=true;
                   clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentData,ChoiceClickType.ADD_CHOICE);
               }
           }
           basicInfoViewHolder.basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(shouldCheck);
       }

        if (clickCallback instanceof SingleChoiceItemClickCallback){
            basicInfoViewHolder.basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(i == mCheckedPostion);
            if (previouslySelectedChoices!=null && !previouslySelectedChoices.isEmpty()){
                boolean shouldCheck=false;
                for (Datum data:previouslySelectedChoices) {
                    if ((data.getId().equals(currentData.getId()))/*&& data.getDesc().equals(currentData.getDesc())*/){
                        shouldCheck=true;
                        previouslySelectedChoices.clear();//so it wouldn't reselect on notifyDataSetChanged()
                        clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentData,ChoiceClickType.ADD_SINGLE_CHOICE);
                    }

                }

                if (shouldCheck) mCheckedPostion = i;
                //Log.d("slctdwf","choice: "+ currentData.getDesc()+", position: "+mCheckedPostion);
                basicInfoViewHolder.basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(shouldCheck);
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (offeredChoicesFiltered!=null) return offeredChoicesFiltered.size();
        else  return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private Datum getCurrentRowInfo(int position) {
        return offeredChoicesFiltered.get(position);
    }

    public void setPreviouslySelectedChoices (List<Datum> data) {
        if (data!=null && !data.isEmpty()){
        this.previouslySelectedChoices = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String charString = constraint.toString();
                List<Datum> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    filteredList = offeredChoices;
                } else {
                    for (Datum choice : offeredChoices) {

                        if (choice.getDesc().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(choice);
                        }
                    }

                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                offeredChoicesFiltered = (ArrayList<Datum>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    class BasicInfoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private CheckBox basicInfoCheckBox;
        private CardView entireRowCardView;

        BasicInfoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            basicInfoCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.choice_checkbox);
            entireRowCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.entire_row_basic_choice);
            entireRowCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
            if (resources == null) {
                resources = itemView.getResources();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Datum currentChoice = getCurrentRowInfo(getAdapterPosition());
            int position = getAdapterPosition();

            if (clickCallback instanceof MultipleChoiceItemClickCallback){
                if (basicInfoCheckBox.isChecked()){
                    basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                    clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentChoice, ChoiceClickType.REMOVE_CHOICE);
                }
                else if (!basicInfoCheckBox.isChecked()){
                    basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentChoice, ChoiceClickType.ADD_CHOICE);
                }
            }

            if (clickCallback instanceof SingleChoiceItemClickCallback){
                        if (position == mCheckedPostion) {
                            mCheckedPostion = -1;
                            //Log.d("slctdwf","removed single choice: "+ currentChoice.getDesc());
                            clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentChoice, ChoiceClickType.REMOVE_SINGLE_CHOICE);
                            basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            mCheckedPostion = position;
                            //Log.d("slctdwf","added single choice: "+ currentChoice.getDesc());
                            clickCallback.onRowClicked(currentChoice, ChoiceClickType.ADD_SINGLE_CHOICE);
                            basicInfoCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }


            }

        }
    }



    public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onRowClicked(Datum choiceData, ChoiceClickType choiceClickType);
    }

    public interface MultipleChoiceItemClickCallback extends ItemClickCallback{
        void onRowClicked(Datum choiceData, ChoiceClickType choiceClickType);
    }

    public interface SingleChoiceItemClickCallback extends ItemClickCallback {
        void onRowClicked(Datum choiceData, ChoiceClickType choiceClickType);
    }

    public enum ChoiceClickType {
        ADD_CHOICE,
        REMOVE_CHOICE,
        ADD_SINGLE_CHOICE,
        REMOVE_SINGLE_CHOICE
    }
```

}

Comment: can you share the adapter code, it will be helpful

Comment: @bk7 Here is adapter code

Comment: i suggest you to add a listner inside **getFilter()** passing the count of the result to RecyclerView Activity i.e.. **filteredList.size()** and based on the count you can set the visiblity in RecyclerView Activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the onQueryChanged callback is the wrong place to control the empty state. You could use a **DataSetObserver** [(documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29) to listen to list changes so you always have the correct size() of matches.

> Register an observer that is called when changes happen to the data used by this adapter.

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        showEmptyStateIfAdapterIsEmpty();
        // access adapter's dataset size here or in that method
    } 
});
```